# g++ -Wall not warning about double-> int cast

Tags: c++, g++

In the following snippet no warnings are produced. g++4.4.3 -Wall -pedantic

```
//f is
void f(int );

f(3.14);
double d = 3.14;
int i = d+2;
```

I have a strong recollection of this being a warning, something along the lines of "Possible loss of precision". Was it removed or is my memory playing tricks on me?

How can i turn this into a warning in g++? I find this a useful warning, or is it a bad idea?

I can't even find anything appropriate at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.5/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$ gcc -Wconversion test.c

test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3: warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value
```

Comment: Yes this does the trick. I find it really odd that it's not included in -Wall.

Comment: It causes hundreds of warnings with integer related conversions, and this is why its is not enabled in `-Wall`. Maybe with https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53001 it will be simpler.

Answer (score 22):

Use `-Wconversion` option. `-Wall` doesn't include it.

With `-Wconversion` option, GCC gives these warning messages:

> warning: conversion to 'int' alters 'double' constant value
>   warning: conversion to 'int' from 'double' may alter its value

Answer (score 8):

Apart from what other answers mention it is also worth mentioning that in C++0x `{}` initialization doesn't narrow. So instead of getting a warning you'll get an error for example

```
void f(int x)
{
   // code
}

int main()
{
   f({3.14}); // narrowing conversion of '3.14000000000000012434497875801753252744674682617e+0' from 'double' to 'int' inside { }
}
```

[g++ 4.4](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) and above support initializer list (with `-std=c++0x` option)